# Extract tarball to target directories without overwriting existing files

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to extracting [a tarball](https://github.com/google/verible/releases/download/v0.0-980-ga8adcd7/verible-v0.0-980-ga8adcd7-Ubuntu-20.04-focal-x86_64.tar.gz) with this sort of internal structure (simplified)

```
[edit: added toplevel dir]

some_tarball.tar
└── some_tarball/
    ├── bin/
    │   ├── a
    │   └── b
    └── share/
        └── man/
            └── man1/
                ├── a.1.gz
                └── b.1.gz
```

With the intention of installing this to `/bin` and `/share` dirs, I used the command `sudo tar xzf some_tarball.tar --strip-components 1 -C /`.

However, this ended up overwriting the entire directories with its contents (i.e. `/bin` only contains `a` and `b` afterwards) rather than merging the contents together. In the *Overwrite control* section of `tar manpage`, it seems to be only about overwriting existing files and the *metadata* of dirs, which is not the case.

Is there any way I can make `tar` demonstrate `rsync`-like behavior here? Thanks in advance!

P.S.: My `/share` is a symlink to `/usr/share`, if that matters.

Comment: If you had killed `/bin` your system would be pretty much dead. Are `rm`, `cp`, `cat` etc. still working? What are you trying to achieve with the component stripping?

Comment: @FelixJN Yes, it was pretty much dead, with all those basic utilities missing (also confirmed with `ls -a /bin`). I just now grabbed my installation media, mounted the squashfs partition and recovered it.

As for the stripping, it is because of the presence of the toplevel directory in the tarball. Otherwise it would create `/some_tarball`, for example. (Sorry, I omitted that for simplicity in the tree structure)

Comment: OK. That still is not what tar should behave like. Not at all. I am sure you are aware of how to merge with  `cp` or `mv`. But that tar-behavior is not right - And I couldn't reproduce it. Any odd aliases?

Comment: I have tested exactly what you did on an Ubuntu, with the archive that you link to, writing to a local directory instead, and the extraction of the archive _does not_ remove existing files. I'm assuming that you did something differently from what you are showing in the question.

Comment: I had the same behavior happening with tar when reinstalling some distros; essentially i just tared some directory in / (mainly etc and some other ones) and when untarring, i had to cd into the target dir (tried with the -C flag too) but it had the same result as you noticed (with missing basic command)...The only way to solve this was to use `cp` or `mv` as the other mentioned.

Comment: It isn't right yeah, but I managed to reproduce this on a VM with certain distros...`cp` and `mv` are the only solution AFAIK @FelixJN

Comment: can't post solution since my edit is awaiting peer review, but you could build the command needed to move _only_ the dirs you'd want (this method currently only take into account dirs): `mkdir tempdir; cd tempdir; tar xvf yourtar; ls -1 | sed -u 's/^\(.*\)$/cp -a \1\/* \/\/\1/' | bash ; cd ; rm -rf tempdir` should do it. DO MAKE SURE sed is building the right command for you by trying it out manually (without the pipe to bash)...

Comment: @Kusalananda I cannot really get the history since it is executed in a script and from the script it seems that this is the only line operating directly on these two directories with sudo privilege.. Is there any typical operations that may result in such behaviour that I might have overlooked?

Comment: @FelixJN There is no alias related to `tar` though... And even if there were, they are not supposed to be inherited into the sub shell of script invocation if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If originally `/bin` is a symlink then the command you used will remove the symlink and create a new directory in its place.

Read more in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/dereference.html#index-dereference) (emphasis mine):

> When reading from an archive, the `--dereference` (`-h`) option causes `tar` to follow an already-existing symbolic link when `tar` writes or reads a file named in the archive. **Ordinarily, `tar` does not follow such a link, though it may remove the link before writing a new file**. […]
>
> The `--dereference` option is unsafe […]

Note a [directory is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690).

You used neither `--dereference` nor `-h` Removing the link is what probably happened.

The directory the link pointed to is still *somewhere*, its content was not deleted. Still, since tools in `/bin` are quite important, your OS may be crippled. To fix this you need to recreate the original link: remove the new `/bin` directory and use `ln -s target /bin`.

Unfortunately I cannot tell what the target of the link was, you need to guess or find out what the `target` should be. *Maybe* `/usr/bin`.

Similarly with `/share`.

If you are still logged in or if you can log in anew then the fix should be technically possible because all tools you need should be somewhere. If you have lost the access (e.g. you cannot log in because `/bin/bash` is your login shell and it's not there) then booting a live distro and fixing from there is an option.